# Operator Interval

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have network call and I want to call it periodically. I wanted to use only operator Interval with flatMap, but on thread of interval. Can you explain this situation.I know that Interval use only one thread and tasks are processed in sequnece.

I have initDelay = 0, interval = 10. Call of first network call takes 12 time units and after them is imeddiatelly called next request. Why is not called after 12 + 10 time units? I think that key is in class PeriodicTask. It looks that network call (decoratedRun) is called and new planning is called after them. But this my assumption is not true. Method decorated.run() is run on worker thread and planning after them on main?

Comment: Because `Interval` emits items with a fixed interval. Even if act of emitting an item takes more than requested interval, it should not alter the operator behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the network call with 10 time units from the end of the previous call until the start of the next call, then you could do something like this:

```
Observable.fromCallable( () -> makeNetworkCall() )
  .take( 1 )
  .repeatWhen( notification -> notification.delay( 10, timeunits, scheduler )
  .subscribe( ... );
```

This will make the network call, pass the resulting value on, and then re-subscribe to the observable after 10 time units.

Comment: I dont need to find other solution. Did you read my question?

Comment: Why did you use take?

Comment: I provided you with a way to get 10 time units between network calls. `Observable.interval()` provides values with 10 time units between each value, which is clearly not what you wanted.

Comment: The `take()` operator will take the first value emitted and then completes the observer chain. This triggers the `repeatWhen()` operator to apply its observable to the completion observable, delaying for 10 time units, and then resubscribing to the observable.